# "iteration limit reached" in lme4 GLMM - what does it mean?

Tags: lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

I constructed several glmer.nb models with different combinations of random intercepts, and for one of the models (nested random intercepts, with the lowest AICc), I consistently get: "iteration limit reached", *without* the usual "Warning message:
In theta.ml(Y, mu, weights = object@resp$weights, limit = limit,  :..."

Here's what I know:

1. it is a warning (from the color) but not labeled as such
2. you can also have that warning with GLMs and LMERs

Here's what I don't know:

1. does it mean the model is invalid?
2. what causes that issue?
3. what could I do to resolve that issue?

Here's what I searched:

1. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67287/very-large-theta-values-using-glm-nb-in-r-alternative-approaches (no explanation as to the why and how)
2. GLMM FAQ: no mention
3. I am not the only regularly running into that or similar problems: [Using glmer.nb(), the error message:(maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate is returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036334/using-glmer-nb-the-error-messagemaxstephalfit-pirls-step-halvings-failed-t)
   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40647/lme-error-iteration-limit-reached/40664

Here's what would be highly appreciated:

A more informative warning message: did the model converge? what caused this? What can one do to fix it? Can we read more about this (link to GLMM FAQ - brms-style)?

This is a general question. I did not provide reproducible code because an answer that is generalisable would be most useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(lme4)
dd <- data.frame(f = factor(rep(1:20, each = 20)))
dd$y <- simulate(~ 1 + (1|f), family = "poisson",
                 newdata = dd,
                 newparam = list(beta = 1, theta = 1),
                 seed = 101)[[1]]

m1 <- glmer.nb(y ~ 1 + (1|f), data = dd)
```

> Warning message:
> In theta.ml(Y, mu, weights = object@resp$weights, limit = limit,  :
> iteration limit reached

It's a bit hard to tell, but this warning occurs in `MASS::theta.ml()`, which is called to get an initial estimate of the dispersion parameter. (If you set `options(error = recover, warn = 2)`, warnings will be converted to errors and errors will dump you into a debugger, where you can see the sequence of calls that were active when the warning/error occurred).

This generally occurs when the data (specifically, the *conditional* distribution of the data) is actually *equidispersed* (variance  == mean) or *underdispersed* (i.e. variance < mean), which can't be achieved by a negative binomial distribution. If you run `getME(m1, "glmer.nb.theta")` you'll generally get a very large value (in this case it's 62376), which indicates where the optimizer gave up while it was trying to send the dispersion parameter to infinity.

You can:

- ignore the warning (the negative binomial isn't a good choice, but the model is effectively converging to a Poisson solution anyway).
- revert to a Poisson model (the CV question you link to does say "a Poisson model might be a better choice")
- People often worry less about underdispersion than overdispersion (because underdispersion makes results of a Poisson model conservative), but if you want to take underdispersion into account you can fit your model with a conditional distribution that allows underdispersion as well as overdispersion (not directly possible within `lme4`, but see [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#underdispersion))

PS the "iteration limit reached without convergence" warning in one of your linked answers, from `nlminb` within `lme`, is a completely different issue (except that both situations involve *some* form of iterative solution scheme with a set maximum number of iterations ...)

Comment: thanks a lot! I merely got "iteration limit reached" without the preceding warning message, but I suppose that must be the same warning. I will look into this in detail